# Can I reduce the timeout for compilation?

Tags: tikz-pgf, compiling

I'm writing a document with many pictures using the tikz package. A small error in these often do not make compilation fail outright, but rather time out. (Example from https://www.writelatex.com/help/46-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-compile-timeout-error-message#.VHXVzouG-ZM):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--(1,1)
\draw (0,1)--(1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, this takes quite some time on my system (texify -> pdflatex from Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7), and while pdflatex runs, it holds a lock on all the files it needs, so I cannot save or otherwise modify my files. I need to kill the pdflatex process before I'm able to save my files again. Since my document is not huge, I would really like if texify/pdflatex timed out much earlier, since a runtime > 1s usually signifies a tikz error.

Is this in any way possible?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I think the external library might be a good tool for you to save compile time. But on the other hand, doing the picture standalone might be better (a little small document just containing the figure you are creating). You can later include the code or the resulting pdf in your real document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: pdftex itself never times out. The page you refer to is a writelatex restriction apparently saying you need to pay to get more time on their servers. Running pdftex locally has no such restrictions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is there any way of restricting it, though? I have to agree that it is rather inconvenient as it is. The problem is not restricted to TiKZ but TiKZ is far and away the most common culprit. Rather than realising something is wrong, it hangs compilation and takes more and more of the system resources. (I assume at some point the system would stop it.) I can kill it easily enough but leaving it unattended is not at all wise, which is annoying for complex graphics with long compilation times.

Comment: @cfr that is an operating system question not a tex one, most operating systems have facilities to limit the resources allocated to jobs and to kill them if they are exceeded see for example (just happened to be first hit with google) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2387485/limiting-the-time-a-program-runs-in-linux

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I realise it is off-topic. I just asked really in case you had any recommendations. Thanks.